# gwt to android using phonegap

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, cordova, mgwt

I need to push my gwt application to android via using phonegap.I followed http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted and this tutorial http://blog.ic3man.gr/?p=120 . But when i run the application i get error **gwt application must be recompiled** .
These are steps i followed

1. compile the gwt application

2.create a phonegap project in android as stated in [Getting started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)
3. move the war directory of gwt application to android project
4. pointed the .nocache.js file as index for android app.

Please let me know  where i am going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue,I use Eclipse IDE,and on right clicking Project option called Google has GWT Compiler,it generates all possible js. Now run the Project,and it worked fine for me in android via Phonegap-gwt ! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

normally when you get such an error your nocache.js file does not match your compiled javascript.

This might happen if you are using maven and eclipse with google eclipse plugin together and haven`t properly selected the right folders for your war folder and the compile folder.

Maybe you need to read: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

Comment: tx for the info :),but i used gwt compile option provided with Eclipse IDE and it worked.